# k-means clustering in R. software with iterations

Tags: r, iteration, k-means

I have 150 Experimental substances. 80 characteristics were measured for each of these substances separately. I applied PCA to compute its PCs and determined first three components.Now, I want to apply k-means clustering in R. software (www.R-project.org) with 1000 iterations on low-dimensional data to separate the individuals to their respective populations.

Can anyone see how this can be done? thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Can you show us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Answer (score 0):

See [adegenet package](https://github.com/thibautjombart/adegenet/wiki) and try DAPC.

Please, read http://bmcgenet.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2156-11-94 I think it does what You wish. It is implemented in adegenet R package as DAPC. This implementation is designed for multi locus genotype data, but the principle is very well described, so that You can modify it for Your own data or find something similar.

It performs K-means clustering on PC-transformed ("cleared") data, which significantly speeds up whole calculations. Finally it performs discriminant analysis to get the best clustering. It is very efficient method.

Comment: Please try to add more explanation to this answer

Answer (score 0):

http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html Provides nice and easy examples to cluster data.

For your question:

Consider some random normal data and some simple code to fit Kmeans clustering. Note, 3 clusters will be fit to this data (purely arbitrarily).

```
data = matrix(rnorm(450),ncol=3)

fit = kmeans(data, centers = 3, iter.max = 1000)

cluster.data = data.frame(data, fit$cluster)
```

Has this answered your question?